# rowSums on one column

Tags: r

**Question**

Is there a function, or a way to get `rowSums` to work on only one column?

**Example Data**

```
col1 <- c(1,2,3)
col2 <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

I can use `rowSums` to sum each value in a row for two or more defined columns:

```
colsToAdd <- c("col1", "col2")
rowSums(df[,colsToAdd])
[1] 2 4 6
```

However, this fails when only on column is passed

```
colsToAdd <- c("col1")
rowSums(df[,colsToAdd])
Error in rowSums(df[, colsToAdd]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

which makes sense when looking at the `rowSums()` function:

```
> rowSums
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L) 
{
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (!is.array(x) || length(dn <- dim(x)) < 2L) 
    ## This line 'stops' the function if only one column is passed
```

**Additional information**

The columns will be selected by a user in a Shiny app and stored in a variable. This variable is then passed to `rowSums`. The user can select one or more columns.

I could construct an `ifelse` statement to check the length of the variable, but was wondering if there is a better/more elegant/single line solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Use drop=FALSE. ie. `rowSums(df[,colsToAdd, drop=FALSE])`

Comment: You can also use `Reduce` if you don't have `NA`s in your data, such as `Reduce("+", df[,colsToAdd])` which should be as fast (if not faster). Though @akrun definitely nailed it.

Comment: boom - `drop=FALSE`. Thanks @akrun. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for the suggestion, but I do have `NA`s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try

```
rowSums(df[,colsToAdd, drop=FALSE])
```

According to `?'['`, by default,

```
x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
```

Based on the documentation

> drop: For matrices and arrays.  If ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to
>             the lowest possible dimension